# Pulling posts tagged with similar title name

Tags: pages, query-posts, array

I'm trying to pull in posts in a page that are tagged with the same page title. For example, if the page is called Banana Pants, then I can call all associated posts manually like this:

```
    <?php
    query_posts( array(
    'tag_slug__in' => array('Banana Pants')
    )); 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post (); ?>
```

However, I'd like to do this automatically. When I try to place it as a variable, it doesn't work:

```
    <?php
    var $project_title = the_title();
    query_posts( array(
    'tag_slug__in' => array($project_title)
    )); 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post (); ?>
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Or, is there a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use `query_posts`

Form [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

> Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As
>   explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
>   the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way
>   to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of
>   the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright
>   fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts
>   pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like
>   making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose.

(the picture there is by this site mod [**@Rarst**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/35541).

Main problem is that `the_title()` **echos** the title, does not **return** the title.

For that scope you have to use **[`get_the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)**.

Also, PHP is not javascript, don't use `var` before the variables:

```
<?php
$project_title = get_the_title();
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'tag_slug__in' => array( $project_title )
) );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Perfect—that did the trick! Thanks for the query_posts vs. new WP_Query method. I've applied that method. Thanks!